# Find how many times an integer is in an array with varying integers

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I am trying to make a small example here.  Lets say I have an array that looks like this:

```
userInput = input.nextInt();
int[] numberOfValues; 
numberOfValues = new int[10];
for (int x = userInput; x <= userInput+10; x++) {
    numberOfValues[x] = x+1;
}
```

So if the user input 1 then the array would be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 but if the user inputs 2 then the array would be 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11

How would I display how many of each number there is in the array if the number care different based on user input.  I realize that there is only one of each number but my actual program is a lot longer.

Comment: Use a `HashMap` as a counter.

Comment: What does your question have to do with your example code, if your example code isn't like your real code? Also, what have you tried in terms of counting each number?

Comment: Use `numberOfValues.length` instead of `userInput+10`

Comment: Your example is going to give you an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if the input is anything other than 0.

Comment: it is except that my actual code rolls dice.  The dice can have different amount of sides and the user can also choose how many dice there are.  This means I cant just make a counter for a possible value such as two and increment it since it is possible the user uses four dice which means two will never appear.  Also the dice are rolled 100000 times.

Comment: How do I use HashMap Sedrick I have never heard of it.

Comment: *I have never heard of it* **but** have you tried searching for it?

Comment: I just looked it up now.  I can't use it because my teacher has not taught it.